# Realm java query conditions

Tags: java, realm

Assume the next situation:

```
//I don't put the getters and setters, but assume they are there
public class User extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<Dog> dogs;
}

public class Dog extends RealmObject {
    //UPDATE: I've added the variable city, to make my question more exact
    private String city;
    private String color;
    private String name;
}
```

Assume:
Person 1 has dogs: NY-white-Joe
Person 2 has dogs: NY-brown-Mary, SF-white-Fluffy, LA-brown-Fluffy
Person 3 has dogs: NY-brown-Fluffy, LA-white-Pepito

Question: How can I query all the persons that have a brown dog called Fluffy?

What I have tried using the implicit AND:

```
RealmQuery<User> userQuery = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("dogs.color", "brown").equalTo("dogs.name", "Fluffy");
```

Then I have read the documentation and the two equalTo() conditions are evaluated separately, that means that I will have:

All the users that have a brown dog AND a dog that is called Fluffy. (So the results are P2, P3).

How should I write this query to apply the conditions to the same dog?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the best approach is to use query by primary key. I mean first adding primary key to `Dog` class:

```
class Dog extends RealmObject {
       @PrimaryKey
       private int id;
       private String color;
       private String name;
}
```

Then first step to find users that have a brown dog called Fluffy, is to find primary key of such a dog. So we making a query to find exact `Dog`:

```
Dog dog = realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo("color", "brown").equalTo("name", "Fluffy").findFirst();
```

After that we are searching for users that have a dog with defined primary key (id field):

```
RealmResults<User> users = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("dogs.id", dog.getId()).findAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you pointed out that my question was not exact, I will update my post, please check it out again. Thanks again, and sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The link queries in Realm are existential quantifiers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification). That implies that if a condition is fulfil for just one object in the child class, the object in the parent class is added to the `RealmResults`.

[Link query example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/21h77z4gzuanxmj/link-queries.jpg?dl=0) shows how the existential quantifiers will work. Currently, you will have to iterate `User`s and query the `Dogs` list individually.

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607) on reverse lookups.